# Using Devextreme React Scheduler to dynamically change schedule (react)

Tags: reactjs

I am using a package called `DevExtreme React Scheduler` to implement a dynamically customizable calendar.

Sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/8kqq12o000?fontsize=14

I am trying to dynamically change the title of my first schedule that looks like

```
  {
    title: "Website Re-Design Plan",
    startDate: new Date(2018, 5, 25, 9, 30),
    endDate: new Date(2018, 5, 25, 11, 30),
    id: 0,
    location: "Room 1"
  },
```

by using the function that gets called onClick of the button on the top

```
  test = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log(this.state.data);
    this.setState(prevState => ({
      items: {
        ...prevState.data,
        [prevState.data[1].name]: "TEST"
      }
    }));
  };
```

When I print it out, the title changes as intended, but the UI stays the same. I am expecting the UI to reflect the title change (and schedule change finally, but not implemented yet).

Any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not pretty clear with the example posted since it is not clear on what the items refer to. But from the sandbox, i could make out that name in setState didn't match with the state name, it should be `this.setState({ data:datas });`.

Comment: What a simple change. Thanks a lot!